# How to include ' in dynamic query?

Tags: dynamic, teradata

I need to generate a query like this

SELECT max(batch_sk) INTO  ln_batch  FROM test_app.table WHERE categ_cd = 'ABC' ;

This 'ABC' is coming as an input parameter in the procedure(in_code). 
I have tried different version of the below mentioned query , but not getting the correct query .

SET lv_query ='SELECT max(batch_sk) INTO  ln_batch  FROM test_app.table
WHERE categ_cd = ''''||in_code||'';

How to include those ' in the query?

Comment: A quote must be doubled within a string: `'SELECT max(batch_sk) INTO ln_batch FROM test_app.table WHERE categ_cd = '''||in_code||''''`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification . Is tehre any specific rule for including    timestamp columns? 
    I'm selecting this in the beginning of the procedure . 
    
     SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)  INTO ld_start_ts ; 
          
     Then I'm trying to update the at the end of the procedure like - 
      
     SET lv_query ='UPDATE test_abc 
     SET seq_nr='||ln_seq_nr||' ,
     start_ts='''ld_start_ts ''' 
     where Categ_Cd='''||lv_categ_cd||'''' ;  
      
   Throwing error while compiltaion if the timestamp is there.

Comment: COMPILE TIME ERROR : Errors reported during compilation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPL1026:E(L606), Invalid or missing expression 'E(5407):Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.'.

Answer (score 1):

Several things wrong here.

1. Mismatched / un-escaped quotes
2. Concatenation operates on character strings and there is no implicit
       conversion from TIMESTAMP to VARCHAR. You would need to convert with explicit `CAST` or `TO_CHAR`, etc. first
3. `SELECT … INTO` is not allowed as dynamic SQL. Perhaps parameterized static SQL with a host variable?

   `SELECT max(batch_sk) INTO ln_batch FROM test_app.table WHERE categ_cd=:in_code;`

   otherwise you need a dynamic cursor to supply the value as a literal

   ```
   DECLARE lv_cur CURSOR for lv_stmt;
   SET lv_query ='SELECT max(batch_sk) FROM test_app.table WHERE categ_cd = '''||in_code||'''';
   PREPARE lv_stmt FROM lv_query;
   OPEN lv_cur;
   FETCH  lv_cur INTO ln_batch;
   CLOSE lv_cur;
   ```